# C++ set with customized comparator crashes on insert

Tags: c++17, static-methods, decltype, stdset

STL set can have customized comparator. It can be implemented in several ways, such as define an operator(), use decltype on lambda, etc. I was trying to use a static method of a class and encountered a weird crash. The crash can be demonstrated by the following code

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct Foo {
        static bool Compare(std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2)
        {
                return s1 < s2;
        }
};

std::set<std::string, decltype(&Foo::Compare)> S;

int main()
{
        S.insert("hello");
        S.insert("world");

        return 0;
}
```

The crash happened on the second insert. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass pointer to compare function to `set` constructor, otherwise it is null and it is why the code fails.

```
std::set<std::string, decltype(&Foo::Compare)> S{&Foo::Compare};
```

By `decltype(&Foo::Compare)` you only specify the type of comparator, it has to be provided because its default value is null.

Comment: I see.  Thank you so much!  Using the constructor of set to specify the instance of the comparator resolves the problem.  The default  constructed object of the function pointer is null.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to below will solve the problem.

```
struct Foo {
        bool operator()(std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2)
        {
                return s1 < s2;
        }
};

std::set<std::string, Foo> S;
```

The original program crushes because the constructor of `set` will try to call the constructor of `decltype(&Foo::Compare)` which is actually not constructible.

Comment: "which is actually not constructible": It is default-constructible. `decltype(&Foo::Compare)` is a function pointer type and will default-construct to a null pointer value. Calling the null pointer then is UB and crashes.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this @user17732522.